# Why is the Avian airship hostile?

Tags: starbound

I've found two different airships now, one after a bit of exploration and the other right behind my starting point (with different characters). I've looked around and apparently you're supposed to be able to buy items from a quartermaster in the airship, including guns (which I've only found one example of in 40+ hours of play).

My problem here is that the pirates onboard immediately turn hostile once I've gotten inside, after making my way up at the anchoring point. While this is reasonable (pirates being hostile), I become frustrated with the fact that all sources of info on these airships indicate that I'm supposed to be able to talk to them.

Comment: What is your character's race?

Comment: Do you have a weapon out?

Comment: My first was an Apex, second is a Glitch. Do I need to be an Avian? I jumped into the ship with a pickaxe in hand, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Hah, wow, just did it again with no weapon and they never spared me a second glance. Should have thought about that after the Floran village, at least they warn you before attacking...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you jump into it with a weapon, you'll be immediately identified as a hostile, and killed in moments by gunfire. However, put your weapon away, and they'll accept you inside.